# Use a directed graph to express a high-dimensional orthogonal polyhedra

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a set of $d$-dimensional hyper-rectangles with integer axes. These hyper-rectangles may overlap. The union of these hyper-rectangles forms a $d$-dimensional orthogonal polyhedra $P$.

I sort the $d$ dimensions in order. So there are dimensions $1,2,3,\cdots,d$. I want to express $P$ by a directed graph $G$ (instead of a set of hyper-rectangles) as follows.

1. $G$ starts from a single node $P$ (each node of $G$ corresponds an orthogonal polyhedra).
2. Let $x_1$ be the integer axis of dimension 1. Each value of $x_1$ corresponds a $d-1$-dimensional hyper-plane $H_1(x_1)$ orthogonal to dimension 1. The intersection between $H_1(x_1)$ and $P$ is either empty or a $d-1$-dimensional orthogonal polyhedra $P_2(x_1)$. Different values of $x_1$ may have the same $P_2(x_1)$. Denote all distinct nonempty values of $P_2(x_1)$ by $P_{2,1},P_{2,2},P_{2,3},\cdots$, which are added as nodes to $G$. Draw directed edges $R(P,P_{2,i})$ from $P$ to $P_{2,i}$. $R(P,P_{2,i})$ contains all integer values of $x_1$ such that $P_2(x_1)=P_{2,i}$.
3. Generally, for $1\le k<d$, let $x_k$ be the axis of dimension $k$. Each value of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_k)$ corresponds a $d-k$-dimensional hyper-plane $H_k(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_k)$. The intersection between $H_k(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_k)$ and $P$ is either empty or a $d-k$-dimensional orthogonal polyhedra $P_{k+1}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_k)$. Different values of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_k)$ may have the same $P_{k+1}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_k)$. Denote all distinct nonempty values of $P_{k+1}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_k)$ by $P_{k+1,1},P_{k+1,2},P_{k+1,3},\cdots$, which are added as nodes to $G$. Let $P_{k,i}=P_k(y_1,y_2,y_3,\cdots,y_{k-1})$ be a node added in the last step. Denote all distinct values of $P_{k+1}(y_1,y_2,y_3,...,y_{k-1},x_k)$ by $P_{k+1,i_1},P_{k+1,i_2},P_{k+1,i_3},\cdots$. Draw directed edges $R(P_{k,i},P_{k+1,i_j})$ from $P_{k,i}$ to $P_{k+1,i_j}$. $R(P_{k,i},P_{k+1,i_j})$ contains all integer values of $x_k$ such that $P_{k+1}(y_1,y_2,y_3,...,y_{k-1},x_k)=P_{k+1,i_j}$.
4. For $k=d$, $P_{d,1},P_{d,2},P_{d,3},\cdots$ are orthogonal polyhedra of dimension 1 with integer axis, thereby can be expressed by a set of integers.

Is there any efficient algorithm to transform the orthogonal polyhedra $P$ from the rectangle-union expression to the directed-graph expression described above? I guess there should be a specific name of the directed-graph $G$. Maybe the generate graph of *P*?